# Cancelling a Task in asyncio internals

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, task, python-asyncio

I know that `task.cancel()` doesn't do anything except setting a flag which says the task should be cancelled([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L226C9-L226C33)), so that in the next iteration of the event loop, a `CancelledError` gets thrown into the wrapped coroutine.

Also I know that throwing exceptions into coroutines only happens at `await` statement calls. The coroutine has to be in that state.

Now take a look at this:

```py
import asyncio

async def coro_1():
    print("inside coro_1")
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("cancellation error occurred")
        raise

async def main():
    print("inside main")
    new_task = asyncio.create_task(coro_1())
    print("finishing main")

asyncio.run(main())
```

output:

```
inside main
finishing main
inside coro_1
cancellation error occurred
```

In `main()` coroutine, I created a new task, but I didn't give it opportunity to run. (I didn't await on anything). The `main()` coroutine finishes but the `coro_1` executes!

Ok I know that this happened because I used `asyncio.run()` but after I went through the source code, I couldn't understand why and where. I must be definitely wrong in one of the following steps.

1. when `coro_1()` task is created in `main`, it schedules a new callback(`self.__step`) in the event loop for the next cycle. (in `self._ready` queue).
2. the `main` is finished, execution goes into the `__exit__` method of the `Runner` object([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L62)).
3. it then `.cancel()`s all remaining tasks [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L193). Now we have our `coro_1` task. It's `_must_cancel` flag is set and its `__step` is waiting to be executed in the next iteration with that exception set.
4. Since the `exc` is set, we reach at [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L269):

   ```py
   ...
   else:
       result = coro.throw(exc)
   ...
   ```

Now how is that possible? our `coro_1` is not in the state that we can throw exception to it. Someone must have executed it until the line `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in the past. who and where?

I use Python 3.11.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

First off, there is a queue called `self._ready()` in the event loop within which all callbacks are ready to be executed.

These are the steps:

1. When we run our `main` coroutine using `.run()`, it creates a new task, add its callback to the `self._ready`, then it calls [`run_until_complete()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L118). Our `self._ready` only contains that callback.
2. In `run_until_complete`, it adds `_run_until_complete_cb` callback to the `add_done_callback` of the future.(it's gonna be called the future is done). what is its job? it stops the event loop. it basically sets `self._stopping` attribute of the event loop to `True`, which is used [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L619).
3. Now it calls [`run_forever()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L604) which indeed iterates through `self._ready` queue and runs all callbacks. (right now we have only one. the `main` coroutine).
4. Note that callbacks are [popped](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1936) out of the `self._ready` in order to be called, so the `self._ready` is empty when execution reaches the line `new_task = asyncio.create_task(coro_1())`. It then adds new callback to the `self._ready` which is responsible for running `coro_1` coroutine.
5. the `main()` reaches the end and it's finished. what happens next? it's time for scheduling its `_run_until_complete_cb` which we registered earlier.
6. Now what is inside our `self._ready` ? two callbacks, one for executing `coro_1` and one for executing `_run_until_complete_cb`. The loop is not  stopped yet. So another cycle of the loop is fired. It executes `coro_1` until the `await` statement(it's now ready for `CancelledError` exception), and also executes `_run_until_complete_cb`. This latter callback, stops the eventloop. what is inside our `self._ready`? only one callback which is responsible for continuing the `coro_1`. (it scheduled itself back to the eventloop).
7. Now it's time for `__exit__` method of `Runner` object to be called. what does it do? it [cancels all remaining tasks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L71). our only task is `coro_1` which is pending. Now in the third cycle of the event loop it throws `CancelledError` into `coro_1`.