# How does the scheduling of tasks by event loop in asyncio works?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Asyncio program with output not as expected

Hi all. I have been digging into asyncio lately about how the event loop, tasks, coroutines,.. work. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59780868) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998823) thread on StackOverflow, my understanding is that tasks do not give control back to the event loop at the `await` keyword, but when it encounters a `yield`. Then the event loop will look for other tasks that have been submitted to it and execute them. With all that being said, I have a test program like this:

```py
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

async def a():
    print(f"start a {datetime.now()}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print(f"done a {datetime.now()}")

async def b():
    print(f"start b {datetime.now()}")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print(f"done b {datetime.now()}")

async def main():
    print(f"time start main: {datetime.now()}")
    a_result = asyncio.create_task(a())
    b_result = asyncio.create_task(b())

    # await a_result
    # await b_result

    print(asyncio.all_tasks())

    print(f"time done main: {datetime.now()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
    print(f"back to main: {datetime.now()}")
```

And the output:

```
time start main: 2024-03-17 11:24:53.119904
{<Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at /home/nam/practice/main.py:24> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:184]>, <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<a() running at /home/nam/practice/main.py:4>>, <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<b() running at /home/nam/practice/main.py:10>>}
time done main: 2024-03-17 11:24:53.120038
start a 2024-03-17 11:24:53.120076
start b 2024-03-17 11:24:53.120110
back to main: 2024-03-17 11:24:53.120266
```

I expected the program to execute as follow:

1. Enter the `asyncio.run()` entrypoint
2. Print out the start time of the main function
3. Create (not execute) the tasks that wrap coroutine `a` and `b`
4. Print out the list of tasks
5. Print the finish time of the main function
6. Print the "back to main" statement
7. End

But as you can see from the output, that's not what actually happened. Task a and task b still managed to run. My question is how did those 2 tasks have the chance to run when there was no `await` point in the `main` coroutine. Or was this some magic caused by the `asyncio.run` function?

Comment: I've provided the relevant explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76744171/13944524) which also answers your question why `a()` and `b()` are executed in your example. The questions are very close together.

Answer (score 1):

"Or was this some magic caused by the asyncio.run function?"

From a brief perusal of the library source, it appears to me that the answer is a simple "yes."  The `run` function creates a task and calls `loop.run_until_complete(task)`, which creates a future for that task and then calls `loop.run_forever()`.  That method performs at least one full loop iteration, as you have observed.

At the end of that iteration, the loop exits because the future associated with `task` is now finished.  The two extra tasks you created do not get finished.

One of the main concepts behind asyncio is that Tasks are independent of one another, unless explicitly synchronized.